# Java: how to return an Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, return

this is the code, from what I understand, it is suppose to work.
Also when I debug my program, it seems that the array is being filled with the objects that the same method is creating.
But still, when I try to print it, it shows me "null" back agian, like the "return" does not work.
Why is it happening?

```
public class Course {

String courseName;
String teacherName;
int gradeAv;
static int counter;
static int maxNumOfStudents;
Student studentsArray[] = new Student[5];
int numOfStudents = studentsArray.length;

public Course() {

}

public Course(String courseName) {

    this();
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public Course(String courseName, String teacherName) {

    this(courseName);
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.teacherName = teacherName;
}

public Student[] addStudent(String name, int age, int grade) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        studentsArray[i] = new Student(name, age, grade);

        age += 10;
        grade += 10;
    }
    return studentsArray;
}

public void printStudentArray(Student studentArray[]) {

    studentArray = this.studentsArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(studentsArray[i]);
    }
}

public int gradeAv() {

    for (int i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {

        int temp = 0;

        if (studentsArray[i].grade > temp) {
            gradeAv = temp;
            System.out.println(gradeAv);
        }
    }
    return gradeAv;
}

public void printCourse() {

    System.out.println("Course: ");
    System.out.println("Course Name: " + courseName + ". "
            + "Teacher's Name: " + teacherName + ". "
            + "Number Of Students: " + numOfStudents + ". ");

}
   }
```

This is my main class:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student stud = new Student();
    Course cour = new Course("Java", "Ronni");

    stud.addStudent("Joe", 23, 100);

    stud.printStudent();
    System.out.println();
    stud.printCourse();

    System.out.println();

    cour.printStudentArray(cour.studentsArray);
    System.out.println();
```

//      cour.gradeAv();

```
}
```

}

Comment: `public void printStudentArray(Student studentArray[]) { studentArray = this.studentsArray; ...` is really weird and unnecessary...

Comment: wheres' the main method?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call that method?

Comment: your code has some curious artifacts involving instance variables and parameters.  a lot of the things that you're doing with them are redundant

Comment: @JoeRazon edit that into your question

Comment: Part of that "mess" is me trying to make it work...

Comment: `public Student[] getList() {return studentsArray;}` I think that what your asking for. Stop return students to the user of your method when they did not ask for it.

Comment: You never add any student to your course. You only add a student to your student (whatever that might mean).

Comment: Where to put this line of code?

Comment: It is suppose to be array of students inside the course.

Comment: @NickJ: we all have to start somewhere. And I know I wouldn't be proud of myself if I looked I code I wrote 15 years ago. Would you?

Comment: @JBNizet what if a student is a Grad student, and is a TA, and has multiple other students in his section?

Comment: I don't know what a TA is, but I guess this would be a valid case for adding students to students. I doubt it's what the OP wants, though :-)

Comment: @JBNizet It stands for `Teacher's Assistant`, and they manage discussion sessions or quiz sessions for a class.  the professor normally gives the lecture

Comment: @JBNizet quite right. I have posted an answer with some code which should so what I think you are trying to achieve. I hope you understand it and it helps you learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in

```
Student stud = new Student();
Course cour = new Course("Java", "Ronni");

stud.addStudent("Joe", 23, 100);
```

---

`stud.addStudent("Joe", 23, 100);` will not add any students to your course.  `stud` is an instance of a completely different class, `Student`, and the implementation of `Student` is not in the code you've posted.

call the `addStudent` method of `cour` instead of the one for `stud`

```
cour.addStudent("Joe", 23, 100);
```

instead

---

I would also like to add that there are a lot of curious elements to your code, some of which people have brought up in the comments.  It would be tedious to list them all.   I'd take a look-through, just to make sure you're not doing redundant things.

Comment: Thanks, it works. :)
How can I print the valuse of the parameters inside the objects?(instead of "Student@49e61582" for example)

Comment: @JoeRazon You need to override `toString()` method in `Student` class.

Comment: @JoeRazon the easiest way to grok is to do something like `System.out.println(studentsArray[i].Name);` if your `Student` has a `Name` field, but the most appropriate way would probably to give your `Student` class a `Print` or `ToString` method that returns the `string` that you want to print, and call `System.out.println(studentsArray[i].ToString());` once you grok that, I'd assume that java objects probably also have a built-in `ToString` method that they use when you print them, so the real production-level answer would be to override that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for example:

Course class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Course {

private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
private String teacherName;
private String subjectName;

public Course(String subjectName, String teacherName) {
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
    this.teacherName = teacherName;
}

public void addStudent(Student student) {
    students.add(student);
}

public float getAverageGrade() {
    float grade = 0;
    for (Student student : students) {
        grade += student.getGrade();
    }
    return grade / students.size();
}

public void printCourse() {
    System.out.println("Course "+subjectName+" taught by "+teacherName);
    System.out.println("Students:");
    printStudents();
    System.out.println("Aberage grade: "+getAverageGrade());
}

public void printStudents() {
    for (Student student : students) {
        System.out.println(student.getName()+"\t age "+student.getAge()+" \t grade "+student.getGrade());
    }
}
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {

private String name;
private int age;
private int grade;

public Student(String name, int age, int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
    this.age = age;
    this.grade = grade;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}


}
```

Comment: it soulved a lot of my problems, but unfortunately we didnt learn arraylists yet, so I cant really use it.